# Yahoo OAuth 2.0 error - 95022

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth, yahoo-api

I am getting error `95022` in my Yahoo app.

My app is online at http://schoonheidsinstituut-antwerpen.com/test.aspx
It just has a button whose click event is:

```
protected void yahooButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                         
    string consumerKey = "dj0yJmk9cDVQS2JsZ1B2YnNmJmQ9WVdrOVdrSlRlRXQ2TkRJbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD0zNA--";
    string returnUrl = "http://www.schoonheidsinstituut-antwerpen.com/yahooapi.aspx";
    /*Sending User To Authorize Access Page*/
    string url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=" + consumerKey + "&redirect_uri=" + returnUrl + "&response_type=code&language=en-us";
    Response.Redirect(url);
    /*End*/
}
```

The dynamic URL formed is

https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=dj0yJmk9WHhNbFFRS2FJc2U2JmQ9WVdrOVdrSlRlRXQ2TkRJbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD0xOA--&redirect_uri=http://www.schoonheidsinstituut-antwerpen.com/yahooapi.aspx&response_type=code&language=en-us

If you simply open this dynamic URL in the browser it is working absolutely well.

What could be the problem? Why it is not opening when the button is clicked?

Anyone who can point out the problem I would be very grateful to him.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `client_id` parameter. The one in the URL that you pasted differs in the last 6 characters from the one that you have in your PHP variable `consumerKey`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it, actually yahoo was changing the consumer key when permission were updated for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for the question, what yahoo was doing was that it was changing the consumer key when permission were changed for the app. See the image i have attached, when i was checking the 'Contacts' checkbox and saving it a new consumer key was generated. 
That was the problem.

Thank you
[image]